# How to trigger input type button by pressing Enter key

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, jsf-1.2

In JSF 1.2 and I'm using h:commandButton type="button" but the button does not trigger when I tab on it and press enter. I tried using `onkeypress="keyEnter(event)"`

```
     function keyEnter(eve){
         if (eve.keyCode == 13) {
              document.getElementById(eve.target.id).click();
          }
          return false;
      }
```

and it triggers the button when enter key is pressed. Now here is my question, I have many h:commandButton elements with type button, what can I do in order to implement keyEnter(eve) to all the elements of type button?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**FULL CODE**

```
function keyEnter(eve){
    var key = eve.keyCode || eve.which;
     if (key == 13) {
         document.getElementById(eve.target.id).click();
     }
      return false;
};
```

To bind all You can do this

```
$('input[type="button"]').on("keyenter",function(eve){
     var key = eve.keyCode || eve.which;
     if (key == 13) {
          $(this).click();
      }
      return false;        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind the listeners use `on`

```
$(document).on("keyup","button", function(eve){
      if (eve.keyCode == 13) {
          $("#" + eve.target.id).trigger("click");
      }
      return false;        
});
```

**ALSO,**

using jQuery you can use the [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function:

```
$("#" + eve.target.id).trigger("click")
```

or by using [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) (which is a shortcut for the above) like so:

```
$("#" + eve.target.id).click()
```

Comment: OP wants to bind the event handler to all buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind a `keyenter` event handler to all buttons in the document:

```
$(document).on("keyenter","button", function(eve){
      if (eve.keyCode == 13) {
          document.getElementById(eve.target.id).click();
      }
      return false;        
});
```

Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your event to all buttons element, you can do like this :

```
$('button').each(function(){
     $(this).keypress(function(){
         if (eve.keyCode == 13) {
             $(this).click(); 
          }
          return false;
      }
});
```

Comment: OP wants to bind the event handler to all buttons